# Xamarin Forms - Access a value of Multi-Dimensional Array from XAML Binding

Tags: xaml, multidimensional-array, grid

I don't know if it's possible but I'm trying to access an element of the double-dimensional array from my XAML file. **First, Does it's possible?**

I'm makin' a CustomCalendar by myself (Which works with WriteLine output). I'm trying now to make it graphics.

There is a part of the C# part:

```
public partial class Planning : ContentPage
{
    public class DayCase
    {
        public string Day { get; set; }

        public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
        public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
        public Color TextColor { get; set; }
    }
    public DayCase[][] Calendar; // It's the Grid in the Data way // Imagine it as a Grid

    DateTime today;
    private int _month;
    public int Month[...]
    public int Year;

    private void createCalendar()
    {
        Calendar = new DayCase[6][] 
        {
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()},
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()},
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()},
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()},
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()},
            new DayCase[7] { new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase(), new DayCase()}
        };
        today = DateTime.Now;
        _month = today.Month;
        Year = today.Year;
    }

    private void initCalendar()[...]

    // Here is an example to access data
    public Color GetDayBackgroundColor(string index)
    {
        return (Calendar[Convert.ToInt32(index[0])][Convert.ToInt32(index[1])].BackgroundColor);
    }
    public Color GetDayBorderColor(string index)[...]
    public Color GetDayTextColor(string index)[...]
    public string GetDayNumber(string index)[...]
}
```

Now from my XAML, I would like to access an Element of this GridData, Array etc. Example in the `GetDayBackgroundColor()` function.

**XAML** part:

```
<!-- Grid Planning part -->
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.71, 1, 0.79"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
  <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.95,0.9,0.7"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
      ...
      <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
      ...
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>          
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Here is the interesting part -->
    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Black">
      <Label Text="{Binding GetDayNumber {00}}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

  </Grid>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

It doesn't work.. I also try `Text="{Binding Path=Calendar[y][x].Day}"` (where x&y are the  position in the double dimensional array) but without success..

Does anyone know how can I handle it?

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

With one Array Dimension, it works.

It is not UWP or WPF

Use in your backend code, in your view model switch to selected the second parameter and display in your one array Bin ding Format.

Comment: Try Mode "TwoWay"